# avoiding loops and multiply lists with matrices elements

Tags: r

I'm working with some lists and matrices, and I'm having some problems to handle the data properly. Let's say I define the following matrices and lists (just as an example):

```
m1 <-array(rexp(5),dim=c(3,3,3))
mn <-apply(m1,1:2,mean)   
ms <-apply(m1,1:2,sum)
msqr <-apply(ms,1:2,sqrt)
list1 <- list(mn,ms)
list2 <- list(ms,msqr)
```

Then, I would like to substract mn from m1(which have different dimensions), but avoiding loops..I mean, so far, I was doing something like:

```
dif <- array(NA,dim=c(3,3,3))
      for(i in 1:3){
        for(j in 1:3){
         dif[i,j,]<- m1[i,j,]-mn[i,j]
         }
        }
```

On the other hand , I want to multiply both lists: list1 and list2 (element by element), to get another one, list3 with the same number of elements.
I was trying with sapply..but I am not doing well ..I guess I could use for both examples some functions (mapply or sapply) , but I can not see how..any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: `Map('*', list1, list2)` for your second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, we can replicate the 'mn' values to create an `array` of the same size as 'm1' and then do the elementwise subtraction

```
dif1 <- m1-array(rep(mn, dim(m1)[3]), dim(m1))
identical(dif, dif1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

and for the second case, `mapply` can be used to do multiplication between the corresponding elements of both `list`s.

```
mapply(`*`, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or we `unlist` the `list`s , do the `*` and then `relist` it

```
relist(unlist(list1) * unlist(list2), skeleton = list1)
```

Comment: Great!that works, I like the first way to avoid the loops, thanks a lot.